# Can Visual Studio Light Switch be used with an existing database?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-lightswitch

I'm a professional .NET developer with a side project for a charity that I don't have time to finish. I have a database (SQL Server 2008 R2 Express), reporting and transactional apps (WinForms through Visual Studio 2010 C# Express). I need to write an Admin app to allow user configuration of the system, something currently done by me in SQL. I'm hoping that VS LightSwitch will allow me to finish this project in much less time than it takes in WinForms. But I don't want to take a lot of time to try it if it won't work. Questions:

- Can VS LightSwitch be used to read/insert/update existing tables? Can it populate entities from views and use stored procedures to modify them?
- Can VS LightSwitch be used in conjunction with VS Studio 2010 Express?

I would really appreciate knowing if my type of project is feasible in LightSwitch.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for example see:
**Quick And Easy Data Management With LightSwitch**
http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/57/Quick-And-Easy-Data-Management-With-LightSwitch.aspx

Also, LightSwitch is not just for "quick and dirty CRUD applications". We are using it for big complex applications. Just like DotNetNuke is still ASP.NET, LightSwitch is still a Silverlight application.

See this site for a better idea of what LightSwitch can really do:
http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be used with an existing database.  The [instructional videos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/lightswitch/gg604823) on MSDN show how.

As far as using it with VS Express, I don't believe you can open a Lightswitch app with VS Express.

I've also, personally found that while the Lightswitch apps are great for a quick and dirty CRUD utility for data, I find it a LOT easer to go to a standard ASP.NET web site, or a WinForms app if I need any functionality that doesn't come out of the box.

Something as simple as writing a custom form to display a report becomes a Herculean task in Lightswitch.  (or maybe I'm just too used to the tools I'm familiar with).

However, the scenario you're describing is EXACTLY the type of thing that I will be using Lightswitch for - a quick and dirty app to allow CRUD functionality on a database.  It's very similar in concept to a Dynamic Data website, except that it uses WPF instead of ASP.NET, and it's more restrictive.